# mixing binlog formats between master and slave

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, binlog

I have a pretty much straightforward **Master --> Slave** replication setup in MySQL 5.6 / Innodb.

Both my Master and Slave are setup in MIXED binlog format.

Now I need my slave to act as a master to plug a Java binlog connector that will retrieve the binlog to further feed a hadoop stack. 
For this to work I have enabled the *log-slave-updates* variable

Thing is: that java connector will better work on row based binary log.

So my question is:

- Can I safely change the binlog format on my slave for ROW ?
- and keeping the MIXED format on the master ?

I Couldn't find any specifics about this in MySQL docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be in the manual:

> Each MySQL Server can set its own and only its own binary logging
>   format (true whether binlog_format is set with global or session
>   scope). This means that changing the logging format on a replication
>   master does not cause a slave to change its logging format to match.
>   (When using STATEMENT mode, the binlog_format system variable is not
>   replicated; when using MIXED or ROW logging mode, it is replicated but
>   is ignored by the slave.)

-- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-log-setting.html

That is "Yes" to your questions.

Note that `ROW` is the default for 5.7.  That is, `ROW` has proven itself to be the 'right' way to do replication.  Galera clustering can't even work without `ROW`.